# Haskell package installed but not found

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I installed diagrams, and it seems to be there, but GHCi doesn’t find it. I tried adding the local sandbox to the command line (-package-db),  but still no luck.
Any suggestions?

```
   C:\Users\guthrie>
   C:\Users\guthrie>cabal install diagrams
    Resolving dependencies...
    All the requested packages are already installed:
   diagrams-1.2
   Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

I find it in:

```
  C:\Users\guthrie\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d
        (diagrams-1.2, diagrams-contrib, -core, -lib, -svg)
```

But running: “cabal repl” or using the GHC(i) flag “*-package-db=…*”
fail to find it:

```
C:\Users\guthrie>cabal repl
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m + Diagrams.Prelude

<no location info>:
    Could not find module `Diagrams.Prelude'
   It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
Prelude>
```

---

To clarify; ignoring the cabal invocations, using GHC/i directly, and the program diagramsDemo.hs:

```
--  http://projects.haskell.org/diagrams/doc/quickstart.html
--
import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine

main = mainWith (circle 1 :: Diagram B R2)
```

Gives:

```
C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop\xFer\Graphics>ghc --make diagramsDemo.hs

diagramsDemo.hs:7:8:
    Could not find module `Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

C:\Users\guthrie\Desktop\xFer\Graphics>ghc --make diagramsDemo.hs -package-db=C:\Users\guthrie\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d

diagramsDemo.hs:7:8:
    Could not find module `Diagrams.Backend.SVG.CmdLine'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Comment: If the `diagrams` package isn't specified as a dependency in your `.cabal` file it won't be available from `cabal repl` (a mis-feature, IMO).  You can get around this with `ghci -no-user-package-db -package-db=./.cabal-sandbox/i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3-packages.conf.d`, which I've made an alias for in my install of cygwin bash.

Comment: Thanks - but ignoring cabal-repl approach, it seems like ghci -package-db=... should be enough for ghc/i to find it. I have the same application on an adjacent machine, and it works fine, finds any/all installed packages. So teh Question is why the -db argument should not be enough to find it, when cabal install does.

Comment: When you use `cabal repl`, it loads the dependencies you've specified for your project.  You can definitely install other packages into a sandbox, but that doesn't mean they're available to import.  The `-package-db` flag adds an additional package database to scan when simply ghci is looking for packages, but I prefer the `-no-user-package-db` flag as well since it prevents conflicts with my system install of cabal.

Answer (score 6):

As bheklilr said, if `ghci` is started with `cabal repl`, it will only find packages specified as a dependency in the `.cabal` file.

However you can start it with `cabal exec ghci`, then it will find all packages installed in the sandbox.

The same is true for invoking `ghc` (`cabal build` vs. `cabal exec ghc`), but note that if you want to pass flags you have to use `--`, like in `cabal exec ghc -- -O2 Main.hs`. Alternatively you can use `cabal exec bash` and launch `ghci` or `ghc` in the new shell.

`cabal exec` was added with Cabal 1.20.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this really answers the issue - I am running ghc/ghci directly, not via cabal. and to have it find packages in the sandbox I added the -package-db=./.cabal-sandbox... option. I have a single pgm.hs file, and no .cabal file, and should not need one. This same procedure works on the adjacent machine, so the procedure seems correct - but the result fails on this machine.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to give some flags to `ghci` to find the packages in the sandbox. I don't know, why it does not work in this case. But I find it easier to use `cabal exec` if you are using a Cabal sandbox. This is also more robust in regard to future changes to the sandbox structure.

Comment: Thanks - I did not know about "_cabal exec ghc_", will look more at that, but it looks to me like there is something messed up with my cabal databases in general. I find that 80% of problems and time wastes and failures with Haskell are cabal related, and I have to just periodically rebuild and reinstall all libraries, and even then lots of things fail (xxHaskell, gtk+, ...).